# Javascript Proxy build all nested calls

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have

```
const obj = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                name: 'final-entry'
            }
        }
    }
}

const handler = {
    get: function(target, property) {
        console.log(property);
        if (typeof target[property] === 'object' && target[property] !== null) {
            return new Proxy(target[property], handler)
        } else {
            return target[property];
        }
    }
}
const proxy = new Proxy(obj, handler);

console.log(proxy.level1.level2.level3.name);
```

Running this gives me

```
level1
level2
level3
name
final-entry
```

This proxy is going to be an analytic service. So I want to be able to build the entire usage of this, i.e. know that `proxy.level1.level2.level3.name` was called in that specific order.

Basically if I were to do `proxy.level1.level2` and `proxy.level1.level2.level3` in my tracker, I can get result that `level1.level2` and `level1.level2.level3` usages were done.

Answer (score 0):

You might recursively wrap all returned objects into proxies:

```
 const proxify = obj =>  new Proxy(obj, {
   get(target, property, receiver) {
    console.log(property)
    const value = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
    if(typeof value === "object" && value !== null)
      return proxify(value);
    return value;
  }
});

const proxy = proxify(obj);
```

Comment: sorry you posted your reply as soon as I updated my question! Can you re-take a look at the question? :D